Applying for a UK visa for a honeymoon trip
I am planning to apply for a tourist visa for myself and my future wife for the UK; it will be for a honeymoon. When we actually apply, we won't be married yet, and even though we're both employed, the savings account where the largest sum is held is in her name. So I have a few questions:

Who's going to submit first, so the other one can mention the GWF (Global Web Form) in their application letter?

Can I submit her savings account as proof, even if we're not yet married?

Does she have to stipulate that she will take charge of me and vice versa in the application?



This question explains how to apply in this situation

It recommends the applicant with stronger finances apply first. You should be able to use her savings as proof, just mention your planned marriage date. And no need to say you'll be responsible for each other, but a brief statement about traveling together works.


Who's going to submit first, so the other one can mention the GWF (Global Web Form) in their application letter?

Your future wife is the primary applicant in this scenario, so she submits her application first.

Can I submit her savings account as proof, even if we're not yet married?

Yes, of course. You should both mention your planned marriage date in your respective applications (I would also provide evidence of it eg ceremony/venue confirmation), as that explains why she is contributing towards your visit costs.

Does she have to stipulate that she will take charge of me and vice versa in the application?

Not as such. She should NOT make promises in her application / covering letter that she obviously cannot guarantee (for example, guaranteeing that you will leave the country on time, or that she will make you follow all UK immigration rules). Cross-referencing the GWF numbers of the applications and providing evidence of your relationship (such as the marriage ceremony booking) is enough IMHO.

Thank you very much for your help. I'm still a little bit confused, I check the links for the "primary applicant" and it seems referring to family visa and not the standard visa. Should I apply for Family visa/Mariage visitor visa instead ?

@SamyAtrous No. A MVV is for marrying in the UK, a family visa is for joining family in the UK. The section in the answer to the question I linked in my answer explaining how to complete the application as a family is the process you need to follow (instead of father/children it’s your future wife/you)

It's so clear now. Thanks for you patience
